# getExtension for mimetype "audio/wav" returns empty string using apache tika

Tags: audio, wav, apache-tika

I'm trying to get the file extension for the valid "audio/wav" mime type.

Using this code

```
MimeTypes mimeTypes = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig().getMimeRepository();
    String extension = mimeTypes.getDefaultMimeTypes().forName("audio/wav").getExtension();
```

The extension I get is the empty string.

However, using the "audio/**x**-wav" extension works.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

**TL; DR**
Yes, this is the expected behavior.

---

`x-` MIME subtypes are usually for formats which are not yet standardized. The MIME types corresponding to WAV format are `audio/vnd.wave`, `audio/wav`, `audio/wave`, `audio/x-wav` (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)). Some browsers accept more or less MIME types. Apache servers usually send WAV as `x-wav`, even though I don't know why.

The official MIME type is now `audio/vnd.wave`, so you might try it and see if it works.

Sources: [here](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-db/issues/22)

Comment: Same behavior with `vnd.wave` unfortunately. I'll have to dive a bit deeper here I think... many thanks!

Comment: In this case, just use `x-wav`. Once again, Apache usually uses `x-wav`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in older versions of Tika.

You need to use a newer version of Apache Tika to get the correct behaviour. (1.15.1 or 1.16 should do it). As taken from the `tika-parsers/src/test/java/org/apache/tika/mime/TestMimeTypes.java` unit test:

```
assertType("audio/vnd.wave", "testWAV.wav");
```

(That unit test verifies that the official mime type is the one detected, other aliases like `audio/wav` will generally be transparently mapped onto the canonical one)

Alternately, if you're stuck on an old Tika version, you should largely be OK to swap out the [`tika-mimetypes.xml` file for the latest version](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/master/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml), though if you're swapping it out in an much older version of Tika it's best to re-run the unit tests to ensure you haven't broken anything in the process!

Comment: Thanks! Though I can't seem to find a version higher than 1.15 on any maven repo for `tika-core`. Any ideas?

Comment: Wait a few days, the release process for the next version (including that bug fix) is just kicking off!